# Which detailed steps to take to design a mould for silicone moulding

Tags: 3d-printing

I am new to 3d designing and printing and have very little knowledge of using the designing software. I want to learn how to produce custom cake moulds for silicone moulding.

I was thinking of using Blender and would like to know which steps to take to design a mould, as shown in the picture below, with a removable outer layer to hold the silicone when moulding.

How to create a dome with a geometric pattern on the surface and a basic form that surrounds the mould?

The hole in the middle is not essential now, but I would still like to know how this is achieved for future designs.

[image]

Comment: Hello, your question is too broad, what part are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308780/19307 for circular array based shapes