# How would one model this crown shape?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to recreate and modify this model. My plan would be to model one of the "stars", which is in essence a star with four points, with the connecting edges "shrunk" towards the center.

Then use the array modifier to create multiple copies of the star around a circle or ellipse, and finally put a sort of shrinkwrap layer around all of it to give it a sort of uniform feel.

[image]

My issue is, I'm completely new to Blender 4 and have only extremely limited experience with Blender and 3D modelling as a whole.

Is my approach sound, or would there be a better way I'm not aware of?

Comment: I would straight up model the whole shape roughly, and then use a subserf modifier to get the nice smoothing and sloping.

Comment: @aidan-j-rhoden So all one big crown?

Comment: Yeah!  Your method sounds much more modular, and I think you could totally do it, but if you only need one crown, I believe it would be faster to do a low-poly model, and subdivide it.

Comment: I think the idea of using a single model around a curve does have its benefits as well. Since after the setup making changes wouldn't be as tricky in terms of what you'd need to select. Though I would combine that with the subsurf technique. Create the basic shape, give it the array modifier, then a curve modifier set to your elipse. Then you can add the subsurf modifier to smooth it out.

Comment: @NascentSpace Yes, I'd like to be able to modify the crown slightly afterwards, such as changing the shape of the curve or tilting the stars slightly. So I guess I'll go with a low-poly "shrunk in" star. No idea how to model that, but I can find out.

Comment: The way I'd go about this is perhaps by taking a cube, rotating it 45 degrees, and then cutting an X shape into the front face for the diamond part to stick out a bit, and then perhaps I'd try to go from there. I can make an answer that goes into a bit more detail if you'd like.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

[image]

I've got a few goals for a shape like this.  First, I want to maintain symmetry: the diamond object is symmetrical in two axes, then the crown is radially symmetrical.  So I use a mirror modifier with two axes and then an array from an empty (rotated basically to eye, because 360/14 doesn't make a nice clean decimal.)

While it seems like there's also symmetry in the depth, that's not quite the case.  If it were, I'd be using a solidify modifier in here rather than an extruded base mesh.

Second goal, I want good edge flow.  That's not too complicated here: the edge loops represent the edges of the diamond and the edges of the ridges, and they can both be represented with the same grid, in a way that gives me all quads and no stars-- no places where fewer or greater than 4 faces meet at a single vertex.  (It's rare that you can get away with that!)

Finally, I want as few vertices as I can possibly get away with, which makes it easier to adjust things to eye.  You can see that here, there are very few vertices, and all of them *matter*-- I can adjust any single vertex to control the curvature at that point.  The smoothness of the shape is being created by the subdivision modifier, not by vertices in my base shape.  My base geometry just creates the *cage* for the final shape.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example you made. Recreating that is going to take some time, but I'm sure it'll be a great learning experience

Comment: I'm somewhat failing to model the "base shape" from your model. As soon as I apply the subdivision modifier, I just get absolute jank. Could you please explain more how that base shape was made? Thank you very much

Comment: I'd recommend learning about each of these modifiers, with some reading and some experimentation.  Minimize the things you don't know yet by dealing with each alone.  I'm afraid I can't answer "jank" from a comment, in a comment, but you can probably find another answer regarding your problem.